# Javascript call changing type

Tags: javascript

I want to write a function like jQuery each and am using the javascript call function.

```
function each(array, callback) {
    for (var i=0; i<array.length; i++) {
        console.log(typeof(array[i])); // Number
        callback.call(array[i]);
    }
}

each([1,2,3], function() {
    console.log(typeof(this)); // Object
});
```

The problem is call seems to be casting Number types to Object types. This causes issues with the console.log call. Can anyone explain why this is happening (my guess is that call casts arguments to type Object). Why would it do this? Can you figure out a way to work around or prevent this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a requirement of the specification when not in *strict mode*.

If you use the `"use strict";` declarative at the top of your code, you'll get whatever actual value you passed.

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/agXkZ/

```
"use strict";
function each(array, callback) {
    for (var i=0; i<array.length; i++) {
        callback.call(array[i]);
    }
}

each([1,2,3], function() {
    console.log(this);
});
```

---

Note that *strict mode* is lexically scoped, so you could add the declarative to the callback only if you'd prefer.

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/agXkZ/1/

```
function each(array, callback) {
    for (var i=0; i<array.length; i++) {
        callback.call(array[i]);
    }
}

each([1,2,3], function() {
    "use strict";
    console.log(this);
});
```

---

If you don't want to use strict mode, you can (in this case) convert to a primitive by using the unary `+` operator.

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/agXkZ/2/

```
function each(array, callback) {
    for (var i=0; i<array.length; i++) {
        callback.call(array[i]);
    }
}

each([1,2,3], function() {
    console.log( +this ); // <--converts from object to primitive
});
```

---

*Related information:*

**From [ECMAScript 5 Annex E (informative) Additions and Changes in the 5th Edition that Introduce Incompatibilities with the 3rd Edition](http://es5.github.com/#E):**

> 15.3.4.3, 15.3.4.4: In Edition 3 passing **undefined** or **null** as the first argument to either `Function.prototype.apply` or `Function.prototype.call` causes the **global object** to be passed to the indirectly invoked target function as the this value. If the first argument is a **primitive value** the result of calling `ToObject` on the **primitive value** is passed as the this value. In Edition 5, these transformations are not performed and the actual first argument value is passed as the this value...

**And [ECMAScript 5 Annex C (informative) The Strict Mode of ECMAScript](http://es5.github.com/#C):**

> If this is evaluated within strict mode code, then the **this** value is not coerced to an object. A this value of **null** or **undefined** is not converted to the **global object** and **primitive values** are not converted to wrapper objects. The **this** value passed via a function call (including calls made using `Function.prototype.apply` and `Function.prototype.call`) do not coerce the passed **this** value to an object.

Comment: @Ty.: You're welcome. Yeah, it's different. Strict mode is the way to go, but you'll need to be sure that you handle the value properly for browsers that don't support strict. Either way, a simple way to get back to a primitive would be to use the unary `+` operator. `console.log( +this )` http://jsfiddle.net/agXkZ/2/

Answer (score 2):

The first argument to `call` method is the scope in which the callback has to be executed. The actual arguments start only from second argument onwards. This would work

```
function each(array, callback) {
    for (var i=0; i<array.length; i++) {
        console.log(typeof(array[i])); // Number
        callback.call(this, array[i]);
    }
}

each([1,2,3], function() {
    console.log(typeof(arguments[0])); // Number
});
```

As for the number getting converted to Object, this [MDN doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call) has the explanation

> The first parameter is the value of `this` provided for the call to fun.  Note that this may
>   not be the  actual value seen by the method: if the method is a
>   function in non-strict mode  code, null and undefined will be replaced with the
>   global object, and primitive values will be boxed.

In this case the primitive number is getting boxed. To see boxing in action, you can run this code.

```
function each(array, callback) {
    for (var i=0; i<array.length; i++) {
        console.log(typeof(array[i])); // Number
        callback.call(array[i]);
    }
}

each([1,2,3], function() {
    console.log(typeof(this)); // Object
    console.log(Number(this)); // prints 1,2 and 3
});
```

Comment: OP is asking why the number passed as the calling context of the callback is being converted from a primitive to an object.

Answer (score 0):

`this` is meant to be used to reference the object which a function is part of.

While it is possible to use it like a free argument, it’s usually better to just pass `undefined` as the first argument to `call` and give the value as a regular argument.

None of the built-in JavaScript iteration functions (like Array’s `.forEach`) set `this`, and it’s becoming common to *bind* functions to a specific `this` value so they have access to it no matter who calls them (`.bind` is part of JavaScript 1.8.5, but there are lots of third-party libraries with their own bind utilities, [like Underscore](http://documentcloud.github.com/underscore/#bind)). If I passed a bound function into your `each()`, it wouldn’t be able to see the current object!